# ionic 2 livereload is not working

Tags: android, ionic2, livereload

I am trying to make work Ionic 2 live reload with `ionic run android --livereload` command. By command line looks like live reload works. [image]
But when I am changing something in one of the html files of application, I don't see changes on emulator. Looks I tried everything.
Added fallowing lines in config.xml

    `<content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <allow-navigation href="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>`

Added this line in index.html head tag

    `<script src="//192.168.0.5:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out.. I am having a similar issue

Comment: damn, this is really annoying.. building apps without this feature is almost impossible.. I will lose a lot of hair

Comment: I can't understand this part 
`Running live reload server: http://192.168.0.5:35729`
and
`Running dev server: http://192.168.0.5:8100`
Why live reload and dev server are running on different ports?

Comment: I dont know the ins-and-outs of it but thats pretty normal... my guess is your server is the webserver running the website/app and the live reload server is basically watching the files and then reloading the webserver when their is a change..

Comment: I hope this will help you https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1425 . There are 2 options to sole the problem. 
1. update ionic with `npm uninstall -g ionic` and `npm install -g ionic@latest` 
2. use this on other console `npm run watch` and update `"build": "ionic-app-scripts build --dev"` 
This doesn't work for me :( but maybe it will work for you. 
Just let me know if it works